# BCD to Decimal And Decimal to BCD

Tags: arduino, binary, decimal, system, bcd

I am writing a **library** for **RTC module** in **Arduino** where the data is stored in BCD. I know how the Decimal number is converted into BCD but having some problem while writing it programmatically. After searching the internet I got two formulas which are as follows and working perfectly but cannot understand how it is calculating.

**1. Formula1**

**DEC to BCD**

```
(value / 10 * 16) + (value % 10)
```

**Example**

**DEC -> 40** which converted to **01000000** in **BCD** which is again equal to 64.

So if I put into the formula I get the same result.

```
(40/10 * 16) + (40%10)
= (4*16) + 0
= 64
```

**BCD to DEC**

```
(value / 16 * 10) + (value % 16)
```

**2. Formula2**

**DEC to BCD**

```
val + 6 * (val / 10)
```

**BCD to DEC**

```
val - 6 * (val >> 4)
```

If anyone can explain it in details it will be helpful.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: `(value / 10 * 16) + (value % 10)` is *binary* to BCD, not decimal to BCD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct conversion functions are:

```
byte bcdToDec(byte val)
{
  return( (val/16*10) + (val%16) );
}

byte decToBcd(byte val)
{
  return( (val/10*16) + (val%10) );
}
```

Why does this work?  Let's take a single digit 5.  In binary, it's

```
0101 = 5
```

Now let's take that same digit, shift it four places to the left by adding four zeroes to the right:

```
0101 0000 = 50 BCD
```

That's how BCD works.  Since it takes four binary digits to represent the decimal digits 0 through 9, each single decimal digit is represented by four bits.  The key is that **shifting four places in binary multiplies or divides by 16**, so that's the reason for the `16` values in the formulas.

So let's take 96:

```
0110 = 6
1001 = 9
1001 0110 = 96 BCD
```

Comment: These are BCD to *binary* and *binary* to BCD respectively. No decimal anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

some code for 16 bit:

```
uint16_t decToBcd16(uint16_t val)
{
    return((((val / 1000) % 10) << 12) | (((val / 100) % 10) << 8) | (((val / 10) % 10) << 4) | (val % 10));
}

uint16_t bcdToDec16(uint16_t val)
{
    return(((((val & 0xf000) >> 12) % 10) * 1000) + ((((val & 0x0f00) >> 8) % 10) * 100) + ((((val & 0x00f0) >> 4) % 10) * 10) + ((val & 0x000f) % 10));
}
```

Comment: No decimal here, just binary to BCD.

Answer (score -1):

```
Maybe someone will need it,

//BIN -->BCD
#include "arduino.h" 
 unsigned long a =0;
 unsigned long x=0;
 unsigned long y=0;
 unsigned long c=0;
 unsigned long b=0;
  int d=0;
  int e=0;
  byte f=0;
 //=================================
void setup() {

 Serial.begin (9600); 
 unsigned long start = micros();

 unsigned long val =964827;
   x=val;
  if(x>100000){
  a=x/100000;
  x=x-(a*100000); 
  };
  if(x>10000){
  b=x/10000;       
  x=x-(b*10000);
   };
  if(x>1000){
  c=x/1000;       
  x=x-(c*1000);
   };
  if(x>100){
  d=x/100;       
  x=x-(d*100);
   };
  if(x>10){
  e=x/10;       
  x=x-(e*10);
   };


  Serial.println (a,DEC);
  Serial.println (b,DEC);
  Serial.println (c,DEC);
  Serial.println (d,DEC);
  Serial.println (e,DEC);
  Serial.println (x,DEC);

  unsigned long end = micros();
  unsigned long delta = end - start;
  Serial.println(delta); 





 }

  void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

 }
```

Comment: No decimal here, just binary to BCD.